# ClassCastException when primarykey is short in greendao

Tags: android, orm, primary-key, classcastexception, greendao

I created an entity which need to identity by `Short` only.

Here is my generated code:

```
public Source(Short id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
```

TestCode `DatabaseHelperTest.java`:

```
public void testInsertAndLoad(){
    Source source = new Source((short) 0, "TestSource");
    SourceDao sourceDao = daoSession.getSourceDao(); //#line 26
    sourceDao.insert(source);
    Short id = source.getId();
    assertNotNull(id);
}
```

When I run test, I got the ClassCastException:

```
Running tests
Test running started
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Short cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
at de.greenrobot.dao.identityscope.IdentityScopeLong.put(IdentityScopeLong.java:31)
at de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao.attachEntity(AbstractDao.java:695)
at de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao.updateKeyAfterInsertAndAttach(AbstractDao.java:362)
at de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao.executeInsert(AbstractDao.java:355)
at de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao.insert(AbstractDao.java:293)
at com.tuanchau.DatabaseHelperTest.testInsertAndLoad(DatabaseHelperTest.java:26)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1584)
```

So, does GreenDAO allow to make `short` become `primary key`?
And, how can I deal with this exception.

Thanks

### Update:

#### DB Generation code

```
Entity source = schema.addEntity("Source");
Entity category = schema.addEntity("Category");

source.addShortProperty("id").primaryKey().getProperty();
source.addStringProperty("name").notNull();

category.addIntegerProperty("id").primaryKey().getProperty();
category.addStringProperty("name").notNull();
Property csid = category.addLongProperty("sid").notNull().getProperty();

category.addToOne(source, csid);
```

#### Source Properties

```
public static class Properties {
    public final static Property Id = new Property(0, Short.class, "id", true, "ID");
    public final static Property Name = new Property(1, String.class, "name", false, "NAME");
};
```

#### Category Properties

```
public static class Properties {
    public final static Property Id = new Property(0, Integer.class, "id", true, "ID");
    public final static Property Name = new Property(1, String.class, "name", false, "NAME");
    public final static Property Sid = new Property(2, short.class, "sid", false, "SID");
};
```

Comment: Please also post your schema creation code and the `Properties` belonging to your entity (you find them as static variables in `SourceDao`.

Answer (score 8):

From [greenDao website](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/modelling-entities/):

> Current primary key (PK) restrictions: Currently, entities must have a long or Long property as their primary key. This is recommended practice for Android and SQLite. greenDAO is prepared to handle any primary key scenario in the future, but not everything is implemented completely yet. To work around this issue, you can use a long primary key and use an unique index for the intended “key” properties.

You could try using something like this:

```
source.addIdProperty();
source.addShortProperty("shortId").unique().getProperty();
source.addStringProperty("name").notNull();
```